# object has no attribute 'save' Cundo trato de salvar formulario en django

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes amigos tengo un ligero problema, y no veo la solución, estoy tratando de salvar un valor de búsqueda por rango de fachas en la base de datos mediante un formulario, todo bien, pero cuando trato de salvarlo me da este error:

```
'FiltroFechas' object has no attribute 'save'
```

He visto algunas soluciones y es cambiando la clase en el `form.py` a **ModelForm** pero es que realmente no deseo usar un modelo sino mi propio formulario

Les dejo mi `view.py` y mi template, gracias de ante mano

view.py

```
def inicio(request):
    plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))
    juridic_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('juridico'))
    natural_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
    general = juridic_gral['sum']+natural_gral['sum']
    porciento_general = general*100/plan_gral['sum']
    ingreso = ingresos.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        formulario = FiltroFechas(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            consulta = formulario.save(commit=False)
            consulta.hasta = timezone.now()
            consulta.save()
    else:
        formulario = FiltroFechas()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = formulario
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': formulario, 'porciento':porciento_general, 'general':general, 'plan_gral':plan_gral,'suma':plan_gral['sum'],'juridico':juridic_gral['sum'], 'ingreso':ingreso, 'natural':natural_gral['sum']}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
Desde:{{ form.desde }}&nbsp;&nbsp; Hasta:{{ form.hasta }}<br/>
<input  type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Ver resultados">
</form>
```

Form.py

```
# encoding:utf-8 
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from principal.models import jovenclub
from functools import partial
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class':'form-control bs-datepicker'})

class FiltroFechas(forms.Form):
    desde = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    hasta = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
```

Comment: En realidad debes usar un ModelForm, dado que quieres guardar algo en la base de datos, piensa que internamente, en algún momento que le pidas a django que te devuelva esas fechas que quieres guardar, django tendrá que ir a buscarlas en algún lugar, y ese lugar es el que lo define un modelo, el cual seria la forma en la que django se comunica con la base de datos, por lo tanto no puedes guardar cosas a la base de datos, si no es por medio de un modelo, a menos que te bases o guies de otra API que te permita acceder a una base de datos de forma manual, y prescindir de django.

Comment: El método save no está disponible en `forms.Form` pero si en `forms.ModelForm`  debe ser algo así  `class FiltroFechas(forms.ModelForm):  class Meta: model=FiltroFechas`

Comment: Gracias brother, hecho

Comment: `class FiltroFechas(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=ingresos
fields = ['desde','hasta', 'jovenclub']
widgets = {'desde': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control bs-datepicker', 'content': ''}), 'hasta': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control bs-datepicker', 'content': ''}),  'jovenclub': forms.TextInput(attrs={'content': 'None'})}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo no entiendo a donde lo quieres *"salvar"*, pero hay algo que es claro:

La clase `forms.Form` hereda sus propiedades y métodos de dos clases:

- `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` - que sirve para obtener los campos que se usarán en el formulario, y
- `BaseForm` - que contiene la lógica más básica de los formularios de Django. Esta clase proporciona, entre otros, los siguientes métodos: `order_fields`, `is_valid`, `add_prefix`, `as_table`, `as_ul`, `as_p`. Puedes consultar el código fuente en [esta dirección](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/forms/forms.py).

A lo que voy es que, efectivamente, la clase `FiltroFechas` **no tiene ningún método `save()`** donde guardar los valores.

#### Alternativas

- Si agregas los cambios a tu modelo, podrás guardarlos.
- Guárdalos en un archivo de texto en tu servidor.
- Guárdalos en localStorage del navegador.